# Help with notation (stupid question)

Tags: notation

I need to understand the following formula:

$$u_{i}=\frac{x_i-\overline{x_i}}{{||x_i-\overline{x_i}||}_2}$$

I don't know the notation:

$${||x_i||}_2$$

Is it the second moment? Please help me to convert it to sums and number of values.

**UPDATE**

I need it to calculate Pearson correlation as dot product between normalised in a such a way variables. Equation 3 [here](http://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1008&context=pcds_reports).

Comment: $\|x\|_2$ generally refers to the [euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm), but as with most things it depends on context.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html

Comment: JMoravitz's answer is perfect.  There are many ways to measure the length of a vector $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$.  The Euclidean norm defines length as $\sqrt{\sum_i  x_i^2}$.  Another useful definition might be $max_i |x_i|$.The correlation between two vectors has a nice interpretation as the cosine of the angle between them.  That's why it's often convenient to normalize each vector to have unit length.

Comment: Thanks to every body. Sorry I have not enough reputation to vote.